# terminal version of mcrypt

Tags: terminal, mcrypt

I'm trying to use the terminal version of mcrypt but I haven't success...

I writed:
`mcrypt -a xtea -m ecb -k "qawsedrftgyhujik" test > testresult`

where:

- xtea is the algorithm
- ecb is the mode
- qawsedrftgyhujik is the 128bits key
- test is the source file
- testresult is the target file

The program gets freeze and I have to abort with ctl+c. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: try mcrypt -a xtea  -k "qawsedrftgyhujik" -m ecb test > testresult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to enter your text and press ctrl+d on a new line to terminate the input, then it should work

edit: the problem is that `-k` takes multiple arguments (man mcrypt):

```
mcrypt [ -dLFubhvrzp ] [-a algorithm] [-c config_file] [-m mode] [-s keysize] [-o keymode] [-k key1 key2 ...]  [-f keyfile] [ filename ...  ]
```

so if you want to read from the file `test`, you can use one of these:

```
mcrypt -a xtea  -k "qawsedrftgyhujik" -m ecb test > testresult        # option after -k
cat test | mcrypt -a xtea -m ecb -k "qawsedrftgyhujik" > testresult   # pipe
mcrypt -a xtea -m ecb -k "qawsedrftgyhujik" < test > testresult       # stdin redirect
```